# Converting a string into decimal number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

If I have a string (i.e "10.00"), how do I convert it into decimal number? My attempt is below:

```
   var val= 10;
   val = val.toFixed(2);
   val= Number(val); // output 10 and required output 10.00
```

Comment: `10.00` is same as `10` it doesn't makes sense to keep `.00` in number, you need to keep it as string if you want `10.00`

Comment: Please, also check the handling of decimals at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: JS numbers don't have a format associated with them. `10` is the same as `10.0` the same as `10.00` the same as `10.000` so on display, it just automatically drops any extra digits. If you want a number formatted, you have to use a string.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're converting it back into a number:

```js
var val = 10;
val = val.toFixed(2);
val = +val;
console.log(val);
```

Comment: toFixed() returns string value. But i want into decimal number .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseFloat()` to convert string to float number and can use `toFixed()` to fix decimal points

```js
var val = "10.00";
var number = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
console.log(number);
```

Comment: Why you're adding `jQuery` when you're not even using it mate `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

> simplest way

```
var val= 10; 
var dec=parseFloat(Math.round(val * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
print(typeof dec )
print("decimal "+dec)
```

> output
>       number
>       decimal 10.00

Comment: Please open this link : -- https://plnkr.co/edit/Hk51lG8xwUnGKc1orIDL?p=preview
I have executed your code in above link. You can see there output that is coming in string.

Comment: plunker that shows string so put this derectly parseFloat(dec) . `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = typeof parseFloat(dec);`

Answer (score 0):

Please put value in double quote so it consider as string.

```
var val= "10";
val= parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)
But be careful - it is not supported Safari.

```js
function customFormatter(digit) {
  if (typeof digit === 'string') {
    digit = parseFloat(digit);
  }
  var result = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-En', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  }).format(digit)
  return result;
}

console.assert(
  customFormatter(10) === '10.00', 
  {msg: 'for 10 result must be "10.10"'}
);

console.assert(
  customFormatter('10') === '10.00', 
  {msg: 'for 10 result must be "10.10"'}
);

console.log('All tests passed');
```